# requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool: Failed to establish a new connection

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Last week I started exploring requests library for invoking REST APIs, it was working fine, I was able to make calls as expected but today when I run the same python script, it fails with below error. Please help.

> ProxyError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=39149): Max retries exceeded with url: http://www.baidu.com/ (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',)))